# How to find type specific references to equals() in the workspace in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, search, reference

I've got a class which overrides equals() and I want to see where *this* equals method is being used in the workspace.  Using Eclipse, I generally do Ctrl-Shift-g which finds all references in the workspace.  Unfortunately, for equals(), its pulling back every single reference of equals in my workspace from *any* type, not just the one where I've overridden it and its impossible to figure out which of the many results is pertinent to my search.  Is what I want to do possible?

EDIT: To clarify.  I have a class A which overrides the equals method.  I have a class B (and others) which *use* class A but do not extend it.  I want to find which classes in my workspace use Class A's equals method regardless of whether or not they belong to Class A's hierarchy such as Class B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can't do this as equals is on Object, take for example

mysession.getAttribute("someobject").equals(foo)

no way to detect that this object is your class type.

Comment: I would disagree with the "accepted answer". It's obvious that "potential matches" might be overlooked and you won't get a 100% correct answer. But for the purpouses of many programmers it would be quite useful to find the "definite matches". Currently it isn't possible in eclipse to find only definite matches on overwritten functions (but instead eclipse will find all references to Object.equals()). I would consider this at the very least poor design, and maybe even a bug.

Answer (score 16):

Let your equals implementation temporarily throw the class Throwable: `equals(Object obj) throws Throwable`.

Of course this will give you a compile error on your equals implementation because it is not compatible with `Objects.equals()`, however you will also get a compile error in all classes which are using your equals method (at least all classes which do not handle/throw Throwable themselves):

*Unhandled exception type Throwable*

Comment: Genius! This is the real answer. (it can not detect all uses, as MeBigFatGuy [pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4061765/822870), but it is as good as it gets)

Comment: +1. It's even better to change the return type (to `int`, practically), in which case the handled `Throwable` is not a problem. (At least, this works for me in most IDEs, including Eclipse 4.14.)

Answer (score 2):

Create copies of main interface, class with a diffrent name. Implement/Extend from these new interface/class. Then search for references of your method with Ctrl+Shift+G.

Worked for me, when faced with same situation.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on your equals method and select the option

`References--> Hierarchy`

Comment: If I have a class A which overrides the equals method, I'm looking for all places in the code base where A.equals() is getting called.  The hierarchy of the overriding isn't what I'm after.

Comment: This method will find any use of the equals method in subclasses of Class A, but not any use in Class B which does not extend Class A and merely uses Class A instead.